# C++ - ListView Custom Drawn on Windows XP

Tags: c++, listview

I have ListView which items are completely drawn using my code. Of course I use data provided by NMLVCUSTOMDRAW primarily RECTs. There are two rects p->nmcd.rc and p->rcText, first one carries valid information and the other one is always 0. This issue is that nmcd.rc does not contain valid rect on Windows XP I get 0,1,0,2 or something like that.

As that did not work I tried using ListView_GetItemIndexRect which fails on Win XP, while it works on Win 7/10.

Looking at the [ListView_GetItemIndexRect's msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774959(v=vs.85).aspx) I can see that apparently it works only on Vista+. While at the same time some other ListView functions that are listed as Vista+ work fine on Windows XP.

Windows XP is rare among my program's users, but still I'd like it to function perfectly. Drawing complete list view on my own would fix the problem for sure, but that is a dead end.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the first comment on this page:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> Handling subitem pre-paint messages on Windows XP (perhaps all
>   pre-Vista systems?) the handler receives incorrect top and bottom
>   values in NMLVCUSTOMDRAW::nmcd.rc, sometimes they are zero, sometimes
>   are not updated since previous handler call (so basically the idea is
>   that they are left uninitialized by comctl32 caller). In order to get
>   correct subitem position the handler has to explicitly obtain
>   rectangle using a separate message/call:
>
> `RECT Position; ListView.GetSubItemRect((INT) pHeader->nmcd.dwItemSpec,
>   pHeader->iSubItem, LVIR_BOUNDS, &Position);`

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried using GetSubItemRect as well and it did not work. In fact I'm unable to get correct RECT even on Windows 10 using this function, while GetItemIndexRect work fine.